# golang: deadlock occurs maybe at compiler time？

Tags: go, generics, deadlock

I am trying implementing a `Iterator` with golang.
I wrote the `Iterator` interface just like this:

```
type Iterator[Item any] interface {
    HasNext() bool
    Next() Item
    Iter() Iter[Item, Iterator[Item]]
}
```

In addition, I define `Iter` which to wrap `Iterator`:

```
type Iter[I any, T Iterator[I]] struct {
    Iter T
}

func New[I any, T Iterator[I]](iter T) Iter[I, T] {
    return Iter[I, T]{
        Iter: iter,
    }
}
```

Then I defined a `Vector` to test my Iterator, a part of code:

```
type Vector[Item any] struct {
    data []Item

    // used by iterator.
    idx int
}

func (v *Vector[Item]) Get(pos int) Item {
    if pos < 0 || pos >= v.Size() {
        panic("ouf off range")
    }

    return v.data[pos]
}

func (v *Vector[Item]) HasNext() bool {
    return v.idx < v.Size()
}

func (v *Vector[Item]) Next() Item {
    v.idx = v.idx + 1

    return v.Get(v.idx - 1)
}

func (v *Vector[Item]) Iter() iterator.Iter[Item, iterator.Iterator[Item]] {
    return iterator.Iter[Item, iterator.Iterator[Item]]{
        Iter: v,
    }
}
```

Finally I run this code:

```
func main() {
    s := vector.New[int]()
    println(s)
}
```

But i got a deadlock, some information of stack:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [sync.Mutex.Lock]:
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0xbbbf60?, 0xc0?, 0xc0000c93e5?)
    runtime/sema.go:77 +0x25
sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow(0xc0003c9608)
    sync/mutex.go:171 +0x15d
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(...)
    sync/mutex.go:90
cmd/compile/internal/types2.(*Named).resolve(0xc0003c95e0)
    cmd/compile/internal/types2/named.go:164 +0x6c
cmd/compile/internal/types2.(*Named).TypeParams(...)
    cmd/compile/internal/types2/named.go:310 ... cmd/compile/internal/types2.(*Checker).checkFiles(0xc0001401e0, {0xc00009ea00, 0x2, 0x2})
    cmd/compile/internal/types2/check.go:371 +0x21e
cmd/compile/internal/types2.(*Checker).Files(...)
    cmd/compile/internal/types2/check.go:332
cmd/compile/internal/types2.(*Config).Check(0xc0003bfc80, {0xc0000c2030?, 0x127e540?}, {0xc00009ea00, 0x2, 0x2}, 0xc0003bfce0)
    cmd/compile/internal/types2/api.go:437 +0x14f
cmd/compile/internal/noder.checkFiles({0x0, {0x0, 0x0}}, {0xc00009e6c0, 0x2, 0x18?})
    cmd/compile/internal/noder/irgen.go:70 +0x486
cmd/compile/internal/noder.writePkgStub({0x0?, {0x0?, 0x0?}}, {0xc00009e6c0, 0x2, 0x2})
    cmd/compile/internal/noder/unified.go:210 +0x6a
cmd/compile/internal/noder.unified({0x0?, {0x0?, 0x0?}}, {0xc00009e6c0?, 0xb88540?, 0xc0000cb8f8?})
    cmd/compile/internal/noder/unified.go:75 +0x85
cmd/compile/internal/noder.LoadPackage({0xc0000d4120, 0x2, 0xe})
    cmd/compile/internal/noder/noder.go:77 +0x450
cmd/compile/internal/gc.Main(0xc74ae0)
    cmd/compile/internal/gc/main.go:198 +0xc17
```

But why？ I tested it and I found that the problem is the Iter method in the interface and its implementation in Vector.
Deadlock occurs when they both exist, and I speculate that maybe deadlock occurs at compile time.
I'm not very good with generics, can you give me some better advice?
Thank you for your answer!(,,Ծ^Ծ,,)

Comment: "Finally I run this code:" How? (In the sense of "What _exactly_ did you do to run this code?"

Comment: For the "Why?" You might have found a compiler bug. But please: Do not write such code: Everybody feared that generics might tempt people to write this type of code. It seems these fears where not unwarranted.

Comment: Ok, I was able to reproduce what you describe (see this [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/FAZZJ5cOARt)), and it seems to be a [known compiler bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60817), a fix for which is planned for Go 1.22. I've added a [comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60817#issuecomment-1728279951) on that GitHub issue linking to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I previously found the similar issue related to the same panic you have as [@jub0bs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jub0bs) referenced issue within in comment (thank you for linking and referencing btw):

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Which is caused by recursively referencing the generic types, generally reproducable when you want to return a generic type as its parent generic type. I made an entire [reproduction repository](https://github.com/nekomeowww/recursive_generic_type_issue_reproduction) that contains all the shouldn't-happen behaviors (besides whether we should write generics code like this) when I try to investigate such issue and try to report to Golang team, you may want to take a look at it.

Though Golang team members have identified it as a compiler bug that relates to the implementation and checks in package `type2`, while panics like `fatal error` shouldn't only happen at some of the circumstances with a unstable and inconsistent behavior, **the Golang team members have also stated out that such definition is indeed prohibited and not allowed.**

My suggestion is you might need to consider using another approach to implement the iterator methods into something like parameters passby patterns instead of receiver-based (or chained calls if you like).

Comment: FYI, the compiler bug mentioned by the OP has been reclassified as a bug separate from yours: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/63285. Good find nonetheless!